# Magento 2 - How to remove Font Family and some other section of wysiwyg editor from a 3rd party module?

Tags: magento2.2.4, wysiwyg, editor, remove

I have a 3rd party extension and for a field they've used "wysiwyg editor" but we want to remove some section of the editor e.g-fonts etc

**please see the image:-**

[image]

How can we achieve?is this possible?

**Note:-** Remember,we've to remove only some sections and fields not whole wysiwyg editor only for a 3rd party extension.

**Update for @Hasham :- path for tiny_mce:-**

[image]
Waiting for the reply!!!

Answer (score 0):

First look for `wysiwyg editor` setup file in your 3rd party module if you claim that 3rd party module add `wysiwyg editor`. It may be like

```
wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js
```

Once you have this file open do a search for “var settings = {“. You should see something similar to this:

[image]

That setting part you need to do changes for `wysiwyg editor`

[image]

Reference Check Documentation: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/

Now do whatever you want to do. I hope this will help

Comment: thanks for the reply...they've used core path for the same on his phtml file.please see the updated section of my post.

Comment: Sorry I don't get you. I don't see the updated section of your post.

Comment: What I want to tell you, there is js part for configuring `wysiwyg editor` setting. Where you add or remove different things from `wysiwyg editor`. You can check the editor documentation as well

Comment: please refresh the page,definitely you'll see.

Comment: cool bro...i know you've better sense...you're right after updating you, i updated my post that's why i said to refresh the page.

Comment: Sorry mate. I thought you are being sarcastic. I updated my answer please check

Comment: no problem alright! till now getting solution,not getting any clue from the document.could you please help me more?

Comment: @wakarAhamad like if you want to remove `B`,`I` from editor so you have to remove `bold,italic` from `theme_advanced_buttons1`  in setting part but make sure if phtml file in the core you need to override in your own custom theme. Don't make changes in core file

Comment: thank you again for the reply,,,i tried the same before this post but doesn't work.

Comment: is this possible to achieve the same in Magento?shall i try the same using design?